# Make in_array like query with MongoDB in PHP

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am building a web app and in this app (Codeigniter and MongoDB) I let people search files by tags. For example if they enter the tags house and cat they get all files matching them. The tags are collected in an array ($tags).

This is how I do the find query:

```
select ($select) -> where_in_all ('tags', $tags) -> get ('uploaded_files');
```

The above query works fine but I really need to let the users search by partial tags.  Like "hou" instead of "house".  I know how to make a like query but only for one tag at a time.  How can I make the in_array search work?

I am using the excellent MongoDB wrapper by vesparny.  This is the code in that wrapper for a normal in_array search:

```
public function where_in_all($field = "", $in = array()){
   $this->_where_init($field);
   $this->wheres[$field]['$all'] = $in;
   return ($this);
}
```

This is my attempt at modifying it which does not work:

```
public function where_in_all_like($field = "", $in = array()){
   $this->_where_init($field);
   $this->wheres[$field]['$all'] = new MongoRegex('/'.$in.'/i');
   return ($this);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
The wrapper can be found here:

```
https://github.com/vesparny/cimongo-codeigniter-mongodb-library
```

Thankful for all help!

**Update**

This seems to work BUT only on my local server... Not on the production server.

```
public function where_in_all_like($field = "", $in = array()){

    $newarray = array ();

    foreach ($in as $value) {
     array_push ($newarray, new MongoRegex('/'.$value.'/i'));
    }

    $this->_where_init($field);
    $this->wheres[$field]['$all'] = $newarray;
    return ($this);
    }
```

**Update 2**

I updated MongoDB on my server to 2.0.4 and it works fine now.

Comment: are you using the same versions of the wrapper and mongo on both servers?

Comment: The wrapper is the same but not the MongoDB itself.

Comment: And which versions are they...?

Comment: I upgraded to latest version of MongoDB (2.0.4) and now it works fine.